# Run multiple threads and stop once one has stopped

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'd like to start a couple of threads that will try to connect to servers.

```
ArrayList<Thread> stack = new ArrayList<Thread>();
stack.add(new Thread() {
    public void run()
    {
        // Do something

        // Success
        // Thread is finished
    }
});
stack.add(new Thread() {
    public void run()
    {
        // Do something

        // Success
        // Thread is finished
    }
});

for (int i=0; i<stack.size(); i++)
{
    stack.get(i).start();
}
```

I'd like to kill other thread when one has finished. How can I do that ?
This is for an Android app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) has exactly this example in the javadoc.